# Node.js req.session for storing user info

Tags: javascript, node.js

This may or may not be a noob question as I have been working with Node.js quite a while, but I was wondering how safe it is to use the req.session statement.

I'm currently developing a web app with a backend in node.js, and frontend in angular.js. 
For the backend I'm using req.session to check whether or not a user is an admin. I know that the req.session is strictly bound to the requesting party. But how safe is it actually? Is this spoofable and so on...

For example, I'm using this code at logging in:

```
req.session.user = new User();
req.session.user.isAdmin = user.isAdmin;
```

etc...

So what I'm wondering is if multiple users are using the backend at the same time, is first, won't it ever occur that node.js will mix things up, and second, is this method spoofable or hack proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An Express session uses a cookie to connect a browser with a session.  A session can be hacked into only by either hacking into your server (to steal or modify data as it arrives on the server), by breaking into the login system (to impersonate some other user) or by stealing cookies after login.

The session itself is only on your server (or anywhere your server might store it).  The session itself is not exchanged with the client.  Only a cookie that serves as an index to the session is exchanged with the client.  The client then presents this cookie in each subsequent request and that allows node.js to identify which user this is and then lookup the session object for that user (in the server session store).  So, the session is basically as secure as the cookie and the session store.  If someone can grab the cookie or break into the store, then they can impersonate a logged in user or directly access the session data.

As such, the overall security depends on these things:

1. How safe is your login process from being hacked?
2. How safe is your server and server data from intruders?
3. Are you using the appropriate HTTPS transport and server certificates to protect cookies in transit.
4. Is the end-user's computer secure so that cookies can't be stolen from it and then used by an impersonator before they expire?
5. Are you using appropriate expiration dates on the login cookies to lessen the chances of a compromised cookie being used by someone else?

The login system itself is often a weak link.  If you aren't requiring strong credentials or your users aren't protecting their credentials, then obviously others can get in, but this isn't really anything to do with session security.

If your server is not safe from hackers, then folks can break in to either intercept cookies or perhaps even do worse things to compromise the server or session.

If you are not using HTTPs with all the appropriate safeguards, then cookies can be stolen in transport (particularly over non-secure WiFi) and stolen cookies can be used to impersonate users and get access to their data or carry out actions that user is allowed to do.

If the end user's computer itself is not secure, then someone may be able to physically use that computer or may be able to steal cookies which could be used by an impersonator before they expire.

---

If all the above things are done well, Express sessions are quite secure and they use the same type of cookie-based session scheme that Google, Facebook, Wells Fargo, B of A, etc... use for their login sessions.

> So what I'm wondering is if multiple users are using the backend at
>   the same time, is first, won't it ever occur that node.js will mix
>   things up?

node.js by itself will never mix things up.  Your node.js code has to make sure it never mixes things up because there can be multiple requests in process at the same time.  But, each request has its own `req` and `res` object so as long as you are only accessing the session via the `req` object and aren't putting session data into variables that might be accessible to other requests running at the same time, then it will never get mixed up.  So, this is on your code not to do something that causes concurrency problems.  node.js itself and Express sessions do not have their own concurrency issues.  They are safe in this regard.

> and second, is this method spoofable or hack proof

See above discussion.

Comment: Amazing comment and explanation, thank you very much. I'll base my code on this info and secure the server itself even more. HTTPS traffic will of course be necessary to safeguard everything